# Chrome hides my windows when I move it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have this generic javascript function to open a window:

```
function OpenWindow(url,windowname,wide,high)
{
    spop=window.open(url,windowname,"width="+wide+",height="+high+",scrollbars=1,resizable=1,statusbar=1,menubar=0");
    spop.moveTo(Math.round((screen.availWidth-wide)/2),Math.round((screen.availHeight-high)/2));
    spop.focus();
}
```

After opening it, I move it to the middle of the screen.
The problem is that Chrome is currently hiding the opened window (it works fine in Explorer and Firefox). It opens it, moves it, but then the windows stays minimized and unaccesible.

The funny thing is that if I **double click** on the link that calls the function, then the window appears where it should, only that its size and height are incorrect (it's very small, and I hav to resize it). Even funnier, is that it used to work in Chrome, but stopped working a couple of months ago.

Apaprently the problem is not the focus() call (I have found people having issues with it). If I remove the moveTo(), the window appears (but not centered).

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code for the link which calls the function?

Comment: If anyone is interested, here's a jsFiddle which shows the problem http://jsfiddle.net/9UthR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a known bug in the current version of Chrome:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115585

It seems the fix is to delay any calls to resizeTo or moveTo after calling open, for example:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    spop.moveTo(
        Math.round((screen.availWidth - wide) / 2),
        Math.round((screen.availHeight - high) / 2)
    );
    spop.focus();
},100);
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it should suffice until the bug is fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much! I also just found out that for this particular case I don't need to move the window, since window.open() may accept position coordinates. This is my final solution:

Comment: spop = window.open (url, windowname, 'toolbar=no, location=yes, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width='+wide+', height='+high+', top='+((screen.width/2)-(wide/2))+', left='+((screen.height/2)-(alto/2)));